# Tablet application using Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a tablet version of app ,which should support all platform like iPad, Windows based tablet,android based.

For this requirement, can i use web application using VS 2013?

is it web page created with VS2013 ASP.Net Web app already having features of html5?

I don't have any web server. i want to use it locally. so how to deploy it in tablet and use.

I google it . but didnt get any clear picture .

Comment: You need to host the web app somehow, usually via IIS.  You can create a pure HTML page in Visual Studio that will work in a table and cross platform, however you will need to host it somewhere.  For cross platform native apps, you will need something like Xamarin.

Comment: client don't want any native app. will web app work in tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mobile applications and web based applications, consider the following:

1. Apache Corodova/PhoneGap.
2. HTML5/CSS and Javascript.
3. Telerik Controls.

ASP.NET is a serverside technology and I quite don't find the application here. If you need data to be accessed in the App, then probably you will need an API that can be hosted as an ASP.NET application.

Comment: how to start with vs2013? as template have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use WinJS application or go for Html5, css3 , javascript

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want exactly? ASP.NET applications might be overkill if it is a simple application. The upside is that it will be cross-platform but you'll need it to host somewhere (for example on Azure) or copy it locally to every device but that sounds like a bad idea to me.

To answer on your initial question: yes by default the ASP.NET templates in the latest editions of Visual Studio are according to HTML5 standards